# XMM Registers Total or Per Core

Tags: cpu, multicore, sse, cpu-registers, cpu-architecture

In a multicore CPU, does each core have access to it's own bank of XMM registers? For example if a chip is listed as having 16 XMM registers (XMM0-XMM15), is that 16 registers per core or 16 shared?

My understanding was that each core had its own register banks, and I would assume that the same goes for XMM registers, but I wasn't able to find a reference to back this assumption.

Comment: Hyper-threading notwithstanding, each core has its own complete set of registers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, each core has its own registers.

It's worth noting that each core actually has on the order of a hundred physical registers; there are only 16 register *names*.  This applies to both GPRs and XMM registers.

Comment: Let me add a little bit information. Architectural registers are mapped onto physical registers to remove dynamically name dependencies that may hurt performance. This is called [Register renaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_renaming).
The number of physical registers depends on the processor implementation. For example, AMD Bulldozer: 96 physical  GPRs, Intel Sandy Bridge: 160 physical GPRs, Intel Haswell: 168 physical GPRs.